# jQuery fire .always handler after all attached .done/.fail handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handler, jquery-deferred

How is it possible in jQuery to fire an .always handler only after all .done or .fail handlers ?

For example, if I have a function which returns a deferred like this :

```
function getDeferred() {
   return $.ajax({
             url: '/test.json',
             type: 'GET',
             dataType: 'json',
             cache: false
          }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert('fail !');
          }).always(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert('always !');
          }); 
}
```

I can have a global .always handler and attach a specific .done handler like this :

```
getDeferred().done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   alert('done !');
});
```

In jQuery, handlers seem to be called in the same order we attach them. In my case, .always before .done.

Comment: As per [jQuery .always](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) documentation ► `When the Deferred is resolved or rejected, callbacks are executed in the order they were added, using the arguments provided` As your `geDeferred()` resolves before your additional `.done` it makes sense for `.always()` within `getDeferred()` to be called first.

Comment: It seems legit ! But is there any tricks to do what I want to do ?

Answer (score 2):

> In jQuery, handlers seem to be called in the same order we attach
>   them. In my case, .always before .done

When Deferred is resolved or rejected, callbacks are executed in the order they were added.
[**jQuery eferred.always Documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)

Therefore it makes sense that your handlers within `getDeferred` are executed before the additional `.done`

> Is there any tricks to do what I want to do ?

I don't know if there is a specific deferred object way but you could pass the additional handlers as parameters and execute them as needed.

The below might seem convoluted and there is most likely a better way but it should work.

```
function getDeferred(handlers) {
    var defaultHandlers = {
        done: {},
        fail: {},
        always:{},
    }

    var _handlers = $.extend({}, defaultHandlers, handlers);

    return $.ajax({
        url: '/test.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    }).done(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if ($.isFunction(_handlers.done)) {
            _handlers.done();
        }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('fail !');
        if ($.isFunction(_handlers.fail)) {
            _handlers.fail();
        }
    }).always(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('always !');
        if ($.isFunction(_handlers.always)) {
            _handlers.always();
        }
    });
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var handlers = {
    done: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('done !');
    }
}

getDeferred(handlers);
```

This will execute your `.done` before `.always` as you wanted. The benefit is that if you still wish to execute something after `getDeferred()` is completed, you still can do `getDeferred(handlers).done(...)`

Comment: Pass it as parameter was what I thought to do. +1 for $.extend :)